# To get last month from user selected date

Tags: zend-db

I want to select last month from user. But it shows only data empty set. Doesn't return any data. What is wrong with the below code?

```
{$select->where("DATE_FORMAT(DATE(receive_dt),'%Y-%m') = DATE_SUB(DATE('".$v."'),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ok for about question want.so i updated it like this....

```
$select->where("DATE_FORMAT(DATE(receive_dt),'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE('" . $v . "-1'),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'%Y-%m')");
```